# How to set value equal to a string in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following code in HTML for my application that uses AngularJS.
I'm trying to set the company_id equal to a company id on click. the only problem is the company id is of type string and it doesn't work. though it works if i simply plug in an integer. Here's how my code looks:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="input" ng-init="company_id = ''">


      <div>
            {{ company_id }}
     </div>

        <button ng-repeat="company in companies" ng-click="$parent.company_id = {{ company.id }}">
            {{ company.name }}
        </button>


        <a href='#vote'>
            <input id="locationSubmit"  class="button"  type="button" value="Submit" />
         </a>

         <button ng-click="company_id = 25" ng-init="count=0">
          Increment
        </button>
  </div>
```

and this is how it looks when i render it in the browser with the ids
Of course, this comes with more than this being printed. The problem is when i click on the company button it fails to change the value unless i take out {{ company.id }} and put an integer, so how to i got about letting the value be set to a string?

```
<button ng-repeat="company in companies" ng-click="$parent.company_id = 0" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
            Sigma Chi Fraternity
        </button>
```

Comment: did you try {{ company.id }} without the curly braces, i.e. just ng-click="$parent.company_id = company.id"?

Comment: Ahh. the most obvious solution.. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't interpolate variables inside angular's own [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive.

Change the following:

```
 ng-click="$parent.company_id = {{ company.id }}"
```

to

```
 ng-click="$parent.company_id = company.id"
```